# How can I use BrowserMob Proxy with Protractor?

Tags: protractor, browsermob

I'd like to capture the network requests made by my application during a Protractor test suite run.

[BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) looks like a great tool for this.

I'd like to integrate BrowserMob Proxy into Protractor using the [browsermob-node](https://github.com/zzo/browsermob-node) node.js binding as follows:

- `onPrepare`: Create a new proxy and start it
- `beforeEach`: start a new HAR
- `afterEach`: write the HAR to file
- `onComplete`: stop the proxy

However, browsermob-node's API requires that I pass callbacks to each of the methods and `onPrepare`, `onComplete` are assumed to be synchronous. There is no `done` callback that I could pass.

My tests run on Firefox and iOS and Android (via Appium).

Comment: onPrepare functions can return a promise: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/onPreparePromiseConf.js

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689089/how-can-i-make-a-post-request-from-a-protractor-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [denodeify](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks) callbacks, i.e. turn them into Promises so Protractor will wait for them.

#### Alternative 1: Using already included protractor.promise

```
  //...
  onPrepare: function() {
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    proxy.doHAR('http://yahoo.com', function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        deferred.reject('ERROR: ' + err);
      } else {
        deferred.fulfill(data);
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

#### Alternative 2: Using Q library

```
var Q = require('q');

  //...
  onPrepare: function() {
    var proxy_doHAR = Q.nfbind(proxy.doHAR);
    return proxy_doHAR('http://yahoo.com');
  }
```

More info [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks) and [here](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/).

Comment: Thanks. You're exactly right. I've created a simple demo (using `Q.ninvoke`) here: https://github.com/afternoon/protractor-browsermob-test

Comment: Hi,  I stumbled upon this article while was looking for a way to add headers to my protractor tests. Do you think I can use the browsermob proxy library in an async/await fashion. I couldn't find an example online.

Answer (score 2):

Protractor easily provides active wait for certain conditions. After starting the proxy on 8887. I used `browser.driver.wait` for this solution:

```
// protractor.conf.js

var browsermob = require('browsermob-proxy').Proxy;
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var fs = require('fs');
// ...
var proxy;

var conf = {
  // Typical protractor configuration
  // ...

  beforeLaunch: function(){
    proxy = new browsermob({
      port : 8887
    });
  },

  onPrepare: function (){
    browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8080/index.html');

    var proxyReady = false;
    proxy.start(8888, function(err, data){
      if (!err) {
        proxy.startHAR(8888, 'test', true, true, function(){
          proxyReady = true;
        });
      } else {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });

    browser.driver.wait(function(){
      return proxyReady;
    });
  },

  onComplete: function () {
    var proxyDone = false;

    proxy.getHAR(8888, function(err, resp) {
      if (!err) {
          console.log('har saved at output.har');
          fs.writeFileSync('test/diagnostics/output.har', resp, 'utf8');
      } else {
          console.err('Error getting HAR file: ' + err);
      }
      proxy.stop(8888, function() {
        proxyDone = true;
      });
    });

    return browser.driver.wait(function(){
      return proxyDone;
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am behind a corporate proxy. Do you know how I can set that up. Few online articles suggested, i do proxy chaining but there is no proper example of that here : https://github.com/zzo/browsermob-node     could you pls shed some light as to how I can implement this?