# Routing protractor traffic?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

So, I have some e2e for my AngularJS app using Protractor. Typically I run them using grunt and the specified browser appears and well, the test starts.

I would like to sniff the network requests while running protractor, having an external script that is executed at the same time; and for each page tested, extract the network traffic.

Do you know if it's possible and how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using [BrowserMob](http://bmp.lightbody.net/), there is an example [here](https://github.com/afternoon/protractor-browsermob-test) on how to record network traffic from a Protractor test using BrowserMob Proxy. and maybe more info on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609963/how-can-i-use-browsermob-proxy-with-protractor) SO answer. haven't had time yet to try it myself, so let me know if you succeed and if it satisfies your needs!

Comment: I've already tried that :) But I cannot get it working (same issue as exposed here https://github.com/afternoon/protractor-browsermob-test/issues ). Thanks anyway.

Comment: will update with another way that i am currently using in my tests.