# Protractor E2E Test Seed Database

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, integration-testing, protractor

I haven't found a good way of doing this so hoping someone has some ideas. Is there any way to seed the database with test data before running a E2E Protractor test?

Do people do this or do they just mock out the back end? Mocking out the back end for me is not an option so would appreciate ideas on how to seed the database. There are a few solutions out there using node but nothing conclusive.

The whole point of E2E testing for my case would be to go to the DB level

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Being in a NodeJs environment, you can [connect to the database directly](https://rafaelbattesti.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/protractor-how-to-connect-to-mysql-database/) from Protractor, but I wouldn't go down that route. You'll have to update your SQL-setup-script along with your changes to your back-end.

There are other ways:

1. Use your existing REST facade to populate your database - register a user, connect with another user, etc. If you set-up each of your tests with unique data you would be able to run them simultaneously that way.
2. Expose to your test environment a special REST point that does all the clearing/setting-up for you between tests.

You can fire REST calls [directly from the Protractor environment](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2014/01/15/direct-server-http-calls-in-protractor/) or [use your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21804302/2685847) for that.

Comment: Thats what my original thought was too to call a restful service to populate the database. Another option I cam across was Grunt as a task runner and get it to seed the db before the test starts. any thoughts on this?

Comment: This way you'll be limiting yourself to reset/seed the db only at the start of the tests which may be an issue if you are after separating your tests from each other.
However, if combined with point 1 from the answer above it may be a good way to clear everything before starting.
Personally I would prefer to setup the data for a test along with its execution. It's easier to manage that way.
Also you have to be able to access the db directly from grunt which may be an issue in some environements.

Comment: if you were looking for all e2e related task within one tool (including data preseeding) , you might be interested in endly: http://github.com/viant/endly/