# How to execute a shell command from a protractor end-to-end test?

Tags: javascript, shell, testing, command-line, protractor

I am writing protractor end-to-end tests and I have to reset the database before each test. In order to do that, I need to call a shell script. Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but trying to work around the XY problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452915/protractor-e2e-test-seed-database

Comment: You could try, NodeJS child process, https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows

Comment: I guess using https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs can help you solve the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly a protractor related issue , but with jasmine. I am assuming you are jasmine bdd + protractor . You need to invoke a method , which executes the cmd or shell script file ,  in the beforeEach block .

one can use the `unix-cmd` nodejs package. OR One can take it a step further , by saving the commands to b executed in a utilities method and invoking the speific utilities method in the before each block. You can check the jasmine documentation for it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using shelljs but I assume unix-cmd would have worked as well.