# How to call http.post using protractor in typescript

Tags: protractor

I am trying to do http post in protractor. The status of http.post sits in pending status and doesn't return any response.

I am calling a method in onPrepare function under specDone:

```
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
      specDone: function(result) {
        if (result.status == "failed") {
          browser.getCapabilities().then(function(caps) {
            var browserName = caps.get("browserName");
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
              var stream = fs.createWriteStream(
                "./reports/screenshots/" +
                  browserName +
                  "-" +
                  result.fullName +
                  ".png"
              );
              stream.write(new Buffer(png, "base64"));
              stream.end();
            });
          });
        }
        new PortalData().PushDataToPortal("");
      }
    });
```

Below function in called from onPrepare, the API takes the parameter from body. I am using protractor-http-client package for API calls.

```
  export class PortalData {
  public PushDataToPortal(result) {
    const http: HttpClient = new HttpClient();
    const LogFilePathInSharedLocation =
      "\\\\10.101.101.11\\temp\\DocStar\\Automation\\TestLogs\\Logs.txt"; 


    http
      .post(
        someurl,
        LogFilePathInSharedLocation,
        { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
      )
      .then((response: ResponsePromise) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Try hitting that Http post from the postman. If it doesn't work please post your complete Http.post call format.

Comment: It works from postman. My post code is updated above. http
      .post(
        someurl,
        LogFilePathInSharedLocation,
        { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
      )
      .then((response: ResponsePromise) => {
        console.log(response);
      });

Comment: try solutions from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689089/how-can-i-make-a-post-request-from-a-protractor-test?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use Http call in beforeAll instead of onPrepare.

You can try superagent or supertest npm modules:

**Example for superagent**

```js
const superagent = require('superagent');

// callback
superagent
  .post('/api/pet')
  .send({ name: 'Manny', species: 'cat' }) // sends a JSON post body
  .set('X-API-Key', 'foobar')
  .set('accept', 'json')
  .end((err, res) => {
    // Calling the end function will send the request
  });

// promise with then/catch
superagent.post('/api/pet').then(console.log).catch(console.error);

// promise with async/await
(async () => {
  try {
    const res = await superagent.post('/api/pet');
    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

**Example for supertest**

```js
const supertest = require('supertest');
const request = supertest(`${baseURL}`);
request.put('/test/sendlocal')
          .send(profileAddressData.createData)
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
          .set('Accept', '*/*')
          .expect(200)
          .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error: ', err);
                    console.error('Response: ', res);
                }
           });
```