# Use Protractor framework to invoke SOAP webservice and call database

Tags: oracle, soap, wsdl, protractor

ForUI automation testing, I need to be able to use **SOAP interfaces** to write and read from an external server - SOAP is the only exposure the server has. I searched on the internet and so far I found out that REST can be used from Protractor but have not seen any examples of using SOAP in Protractor (see [Bare HTTP Calls from Protractor Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055960/bare-http-calls-from-protractor-tests)
 (for Bomi/Yogesh and Stiggler answers) and [Direct Server Http Calls in Protractor](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2014/01/15/direct-server-http-calls-in-protractor/)...can SOAP be directly called from Protractor?

Also, for some other tasks, need to be able to run SQL statements / procedures on an Oracle server. node-oracledb npm was recommended but it seems to be such a big hassle to install. What is the best library to use when it comes to Oracle / Protractor interactions?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the problem that you should try to solve with protractor. Protractor is cool tool for manipulating with browsers, but for all other things it is better to use tools that was designed for them.

You can put any nodejs libraries to your project and use them. Just be sure that you execute them in correct place in your tests.

For example - here is library for soap - https://www.npmjs.com/package/easysoap

And for oracle:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracle

BTW: In this example - http://squirrel.pl/blog/2014/01/15/direct-server-http-calls-in-protractor/
additional node js module used - 'requests', that is not protractor feature.

Comment: I made easySoap work with a simple parameter case. I will be looking for how to make it work with my actual case which is more complex (I do not know how nested parameters below this can be coded in easySoap). 

`<ServiceRequestInfo>
                <siri1:RequestTimestamp>2013-05-22T12:20:40+02:00</siri1:RequestTimestamp>
                <siri1:RequestorRef>SWM</siri1:RequestorRef>
            </ServiceRequestInfo>
`

Comment: here is the simple case that works (apologies for lack of proper format)-please provide any reference for using the complex parameters case in the comment above.

`

Comment: I searched a lot on the internet...easysoap just does not work for somereason....not even sure how to post my code here...my WSDL has nested tags and different namespaces for different tage...not sure how to structure them in the JSON format that easysoap wants....

Comment: Also, I am thinking that I do need to have some sort of module that can be used in Protractor (Node module easysoap would have worked but the problem is that I cannot get it to do what I want). The reason I want Protractor to have this, is because before each test I need to create some data and after each test delete some data. This is a very common task in E2E testing as you know...but now sure why Protractor/Node/Angular do not have a well-documented and clear example of showing how to work with complex WSDLs. I know that I may be not understanding it...I really need help

Comment: It is not so common, and will overload Protractor with dependencies. 
I am also preparing some data in tests thru database - but have no problems with running 3rd party libraries before and after each test. Please make sure that you are using library for soap requests correctly - it might be any other, not specially easySoap - just use any that works better for you. If you have other questions regarding how to send specific request with that library, please create separate question to not spam in comments. Thanks!

Comment: Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb instead of the unmaintained https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracle