# End to End testing in protractor framework + AngularJs + calling an action from protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have an application in angularJs and in that I have 1 test case in protractor framework.I want to call a backend action of Java from protractor test case.How can I do that.
ajax, http, jquery actions are not working
I have tried the followings:
1)

```
 $.ajax({
            url : '/url',
            type : 'GET/POST',
            data : {
                'param1' : val1,
                "param2" : val2
            },
            success : function(json) {
                console.log('success:'+json);
                }
            }
        });
```

2)

```
 $.getJSON('/url', {
            "param1" : val1,
            "param2" : val2
        }, function(json) {
            console.log('success:'+json);
        });
```

3)

```
$http.get('/url', {
            params : {
                'param1' : val1,
                                'param2' : val2
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log('success:'+json);
        });
```

but that all are not working.

Please help me with an example
thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `browser.executeAsyncScript`

Take a look at this example: 
[Accessing Angular inside Protractor Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619225/accessing-angular-inside-protractor-test/20620056#20620056)

Answer (score 0):

**Protractor** is e2e framework that means you can test only user interactions (in browser).
For unit tests(making deeper testing for ajax calls) use [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html) test runner.

Comment: Accepted.There is any way of integrate protractor with JUnit!.I have testcases in JUnit. And now frontend is converted in Angular. So I am thinking that use protractor library in JUnit and use advantage of protractor in JUnit.
Is this possible or not? there is any way to do this?