# view doesn't load when I mock backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to test one particular element of user interface. To do so I need particular request to my backend to respond with predefined data, but all other requests should pass through. Here's how I do it (coffee for more readability):

```
describe 'select2 combobox widget', ()->
  httpBackendMock = () ->
     angular.module 'httpBackendMock', ['ngMockE2E', 'fmAppApp']
        .run ($httpBackend)->
            dummyCategories = [
               {id: 1, name: 'foo', icon: '', user_id: 5},
               {id: 2, name: 'bar', icon: '', user_id: 5},
               {id: 3, name: 'baz', icon: '', user_id: 5},
               {id: 4, name: 'quax', icon: '', user_id: 5}
            ]

            $httpBackend.whenGET '/api/categories'
                .respond ()->
                    [200, dummyCategories]
            $httpBackend.whenGET /.*/
                .passThrough()
            $httpBackend.whenGET /^\/views\//
                .passThrough()
            $httpBackend.whenGET /^\/scripts\/.*/
                .passThrough()
            $httpBackend.whenGET /^\/scripts\//
                .passThrough()
            $httpBackend.whenGET /^\/bower_components\//
                .passThrough()
            $httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).passThrough()

  browser
     .addMockModule 'httpBackendMock', httpBackendMock
```

so basically what I do here is create new module on top of my application module `fmAppApp` and angular `ngMockE2E` and tell Protractor about it.

And for the sake of completeness I'll show here one simple statement inside this `describe` block:

```
it 'should allow user to type in anything', ()->
    browser.get 'http://localhost:9000/#/'
    element By.model 'category.selected'
        .click()
    input = element By.css '.ui-select-search'
    input.sendKeys 'newtestcategory'
    expect input.getAttribute('value')
        .toBe 'newtestcategory'
```

when I run grunt protractor it opens browser, navigates to specified url (`http://localhost:9000/#/`) as it should and then I see blank page and spec failures with this error:
`NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.model("category.selected")`

Unfortunately this message is all I have since I can't open firebug and see what went wrong for obvious reasons. I guess I could redirect logging from browser console somehow and see what is root of evil here but I don't know how. Maybe someone encountered that as well and knows what it might be?
Update:
I did as Cétia below suggested and I got this message in logs:

`message: 'http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js 11607:24 Error: Unexpected request: POST /api/login`

Now why is that? Should I add 'api/login' to passThrough() ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946840/protractor-tests-inconsistently-passing-failing-for-angularjs-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I didn't provide sufficient information. I left out some code that I thought was irrelevant with intent to not overwhelm you, but as it turned out it was a stumbling block.

```
browser.get 'http://localhost:9000/#/'
element By.model 'email'
  .sendKeys 'dima@mail'
element By.model 'password'
  .sendKeys '123456'
element By.cssContainingText 'form[name=login] button', 'Войти'
  .click()
```

This code is responsible for logging user in, I need it here because unauthorized users aren't allowed to see the view I wanted to test. 
I thought I made sure **all** requests make it through, but of course I forgot that my login request is a **POST** request. So problem was solved simply by adding

```
$httpBackend.whenPOST /.*/
      .passThrough()
```

Answer (score 2):

To be sure that your mock is loaded, you can add `console.log` inside, and, in your protractor test add :

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
    console.log('log: ' + require('util').inspect(browserLog));
});
```

In order to output browser logs in your protractor console (after your `browser.get`).

Comment: Is this really an answer or a comment / tip on how to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Although it isn't direct answer to my question, but without it I wouldn't be able to get to the truth, so thank you.