# Access $scope object with protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I got an object like:

```
$scope.project = {name: 'whatever', description: 'blabla', another: 'another'};
```

To debug this, I enter in repl mode and try to see what "project" has.
When I define project variable as below, and call it, it returns my object, but when I try to access its keys (project.name), I get undefined. If I do `Object.keys(project)` I am getting the page object methods like click, getAttribute, etc.

Any ideas on how can I have access to the original object keys?

View side:

```
<h1 id="foo">{{project.name}}</h1>
```

Test side:

```
var project = element(by.id('foo')).evaluate('project');
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`evaluate` uses `executeScript` behind the scenes. It returns an `ElementFinder` which resolves to the object you are looking for:

```
var project;
element(by.id('foo')).evaluate('project').then(function(value) {
    project = value;
});
```

The [documentation](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.evaluate) says:

> which resolves to the evaluated expression for each underlying
>   element. The result will be resolved as in
>   webdriver.WebDriver.executeScript. In summary - primitives will be
>   resolved as is, functions will be converted to string, and elements
>   will be returned as a WebElement.

Also, check out [Accessing Angular inside Protractor Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619225/accessing-angular-inside-protractor-test)

Edit: syntax error

Comment: seems some syntax error. It should be `element(by.id('foo')).evaluate('project').then(function(value) {
                project = value;     });`

Comment: what does `value` represent?

Comment: evaluate uses Promise. the value should give the returned data after evaluating 'project'