# How to execute "angular.element().scope()" in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I'd like to access scopes of Angular app module like this

```
var scopes = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('[ng-app]')).scope();
```

but I can't figure out how we use it in Protractor. I tried:

```
1) var scopes = element(by.css(['ng-app'])).scope()
2) var scopes = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('[ng-app]')).scope()
```

But all of these 2 options return "undefined is not function" or for 2nd option "angular is not defined"

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20620056/771848, may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @alecxe. If I wrap the code mentioned above in

```
browser.executeAsyncScript
```

it will work