# Check angular ui route state using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, protractor, state

I'm using protractor framework to test my angular application.

Can I check for the angular state in the e2e test?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, the idea is to use [`browser.executeAsyncScript()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeAsyncScript) to:

- locate the element having the `ng-app` defined
- initialize the [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) and get the `injector` instance
- get the [`$state` service](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)
- use [`$state.current.name`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#properties_current) to get the *current state's name*

Sample working test using the [UI router demo page](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/):

```
describe("Current Angular UI router state", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get("https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/");
    });

    it("should get the current state", function (){
        var currentStateName = browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback) {
            var el = document.querySelector("html");  // ng-app is defined on html element in this case
            var injector = angular.element(el).injector();
            var service = injector.get('$state');

            callback(service.current.name);
        });

        expect(currentStateName).toEqual("home");
    });
});
```

Heavily inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20620056/771848).