# How to hook protractor to angular ui router state transition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, protractor

I would like to use Protractor to perform automatic screenshots across all our e2e tests.

The purpose for that is to be able to review those screenshots occasionally in case there're some visual slips we introduced. My idea to accomplish this **automatically** is to take a screenshot after angular ui router performs state transition.

The transition is a good indication we'll be looking at a different view. My question thus is, is it possible for Protractor to hook up to state transition?

Comment: This should be a good start: [Check angular ui route state using protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501054/check-angular-ui-route-state-using-protractor).

Answer (score 0):

For AngularJS (1) you **can** use mockModules, I don't exactly know if you can hook onto the router then. With Angular (2) you **can't** use mockModules.

Possible alternatives are:

- listen to url changes
- Create a customer methods that also adds taking a screenshot after url change when you click on an element that results in a route change.

Hope it helps